# java script program to handle http post request

Tags: javascript

I just want a java script program to handle http post request

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"?  Send an HTTP POST request?  Respond to the request and send a reply?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) support lets you submit HTTP POSTs from a web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it to send one, but not do much to very much to really handle it.
Maybe there is some solution to what you want to do if you explain more what you are after.